# Remove brackets and quotations from JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

Hi I am using AngularJS on a WordPress site and when displaying custom field values using Angular tags in my partials HTML file such as `{{post.manualest}}`, it displays as `["1,500,000"]`

How can I remove `[" "]` so that it shows only `1,500,000`?

Comment: try `{{post.manualest[0]}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `{{post.manualest}}` contains an array you need `ng-repeat`

```
<p ng-repeat="tag in post.manualest">{{tag}}</p>
```

> The **ngRepeat** directive instantiates a template once per item from
>   a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the
>   given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and `$index`
>   is set to the item index or key.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: wow thanks for the speedy reply. That's weird that its an array when its suppose to be a single value. Maybe you can help me with a couple other questions if you're familiar with wordpress -- http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216980/how-to-display-term-name-angularjs    and    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216785/angularjs-not-displaying-all-posts   ... Thanks either way!

Answer (score 1):

The data you received (in `manualest` key) is an Array. So either you can use the `ng-repeat` as @Vicky suggested or you can simply write in your HTML:

```
{{post.manualest[0]}}
```

**Edit**: Like @FuzzyTree already mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I like this answer for its simplicity